# Projective representations of restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(3,1)$ are the same as the representations of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

In many Physics textbooks, I have seen $($what appears to me to be$)$ the claim that every representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, the universal cover of $SO^+(3,1)$, is a projective representations of $SO^+(3,1)$, and vice versa. Is this true? And if so, how do we go about proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** "In many Physics textbooks, I have seen (what appears to me to be) the claim that every representation of $SL(2,C)$, the universal cover of $SO^+(3,1)$, is a projective representations of $SO^+(3,1)$, and vice versa. Is this true? And if so, how do we go about proving this?"

**Answer:** In Hall, "Lie groups, Lie algebras.." you find an elementary study of  $SU(2), SO(3), SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and their representations. In prop 3.27 they study irreducible $SO(3)$-representations in terms of $SU(2)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. The group $SO^+(3,1)$ is also studied and you may find the relation you seek or a reference in the book.

**Note:** For any map $\rho: \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)$, there is a canonical isomorphism (Frobenius reciprocity)

$$Hom_{U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))-mod}(W, U) \cong $$

$$Hom_{U(\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1))-mod}( U(\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)) \otimes W, U)$$

for any $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module $W$ and  $\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)$-module $U$, and you may study this principle for irreducible modules.

For any $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module $W$ you get canonically an $\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)$-module $\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)\otimes W$, and then you must study what happens to irreducible modules.  Irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ modules are the modules $V_m:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]_m$ (homogeneous polynomials in $x,y$ of degree $m$) and you must study what happens to $V_m$ when you tensor - does it stay irreducible? In general if

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow 0$$

is an exact sequence and if $V(\lambda):=U(\mathfrak{g})/I$ is an irreducible $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module, it follows

$$U(\mathfrak{h})\otimes_{U(\mathfrak{g})} V(\lambda) \cong V(\lambda)/JV(\lambda)$$

where $J \subseteq U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the 2-sided ideal generated by $I$.